# Electrical energy (J) from voltage (V), amperage (A) and exposure duration (s)

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, power

I have that the electrical energy $E$ in Joules (J) is equal to $E = time \times current^2 \times resistance$.

Reasoning with SI units, we can verify that this equation **does return energy values in [Joules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule)**. Indeed, the resistance is in [ohms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm), or $kg⋅m^2⋅s^{−3}⋅A^{−2}$. So we get $s \times A^2 \times kg⋅m^2⋅s^{−3}⋅A^{−2} \rightarrow kg⋅m^2⋅s^{-2} \rightarrow J$.

**However, when trying with real values, something is off**.
E.g., a one-second exposure to a 100 mA current gives, assuming the [resistance of the wet human body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_injury#Body_resistance) is 1000 ohms, $E = 1 \times 0.1^2 \times 1000 = 10$ J. This is a very low amount of energy. Yet, it is well known that currents of 100 mA are lethal (I would assume even more when one is wetted).
Another thing that seems off is that increasing the resistance increases the amount of energy. Which means that with a dry body of resistance 100,000 ohms, the injury will be much more severe than with a wet body, which again does not make sense to me.

I am aware that we also have $E = time \times current \times voltage$ (volt-amperes are watts, which, multiplied by seconds, give Joules). Assuming again a 100 mA current and a resistance of 1000 ohms, we get by ohms's law a voltage of $0.1\times1000 = 100$ V, and an energy value of $E = 1 \times 0.1 \times 100 = 10$ J (assuming the same one-second exposure). Same very low value.

**I am obviously missing something here. What is wrong with my interpretation of the equations? What am I missing to accurately estimate the electrical energy in Joules in a way that is consistent with common sense about injury severity?**

Comment: I think what you are missing is that the impedance of the skin is voltage dependent.

Comment: RE "with a dry body of resistance 100,000 ohms, the injury will be much more severe", why do you think that the current will stay the same if the body resistance changes?

Answer (score 1):

> **However, when trying with real values, something is off**.\ E.g., a one-second exposure to a 100 mA current gives, assuming the
> [resistance of the wet human body][4] is 1000 ohms, $E = 1 \times
> > 0.1^2 \times 1000 = 10$ J. This is a very low amount of energy.

I suspect that many of the references in the Wikipedia article got their information from IEC 60479-1: Effects of current on human beings and livestock; a document that I am fairly familiar with. In any event, the thresholds for various physiological effects are current thresholds, not energy thresholds.

> Yet, it is well known that currents of 100 mA are lethal (I would
> assume even more when one is wetted).

As I recall, IEC 60479-1 states the threshold of ventricular fibrillation of about 30 mA rms for 50/60 Hz ac current and an exposure time on the order of 1 second.   Wetting the body reduces the body impedance so that more current will flow for a given voltage. But wetting the body does not affect the magnitude of the threshold current.

> Another thing that seems off is that increasing the resistance
> increases the amount of energy. Which means that with a dry body of
> resistance 100,000 ohms, the injury will be much more severe than with
> a wet body, which again does not make sense to me.

Increasing the body resistance does not increase the amount of energy because a higher body resistance is associated with a lower applied voltage. A body resistance of 100,000 Ohms would primarily be skin resistance and skin resistance is a function of voltage a well as wetness.

For example, according to IEC 60479-1 at 50/60 Hz hand to hand dry contact body impedance is in the range of 5000-6000 ohms at 10 vac.  A total body impedance of 100,000 ohms would be an even lower voltage. But lets say its 10 vac. Then the current would be 10/100,000 = 0.1 mA. The energy for 1 second would only be 1 mJ. Even less because 100,000 Ohms body impedance corresponds to a voltage less than 10 vac.

> I am obviously missing something here. What is wrong with my
> interpretation of the equations? What am I missing to accurately
> estimate the electrical energy in Joules in a way that is consistent
> with common sense about injury severity?

What you are missing is the inverse relationship between body impedance and voltage. Body impedance, which is primarily skin impedance, can be very high but only when the voltage is very low. What you are also missing is that the thresholds for electric shock injury severity are based on current not energy.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing to accurately estimate the electrical energy in Joules in a way that is consistent with common sense about injury severity?

The sources that we are most likely to be shocked by (i.e. our household mains) are constant voltage sources, not constant current.

So we should use the constant voltage form of the equation for power delivered to a resistor

$$P = \frac{V^2}{R}.$$

If you're in a 220 V country, then, for a 1000 ohm resistor we have

$$P = \frac{(220\ {\rm V})^2}{1000\ {\rm\Omega}} = 48.4\ {\rm W}$$

and for a 100,000 ohm load we have

$$P = \frac{(220\ {\rm V})^2}{1000000\ {\rm\Omega}} = 0.0484\ {\rm W}$$

So the exposure is much reduced, as you have correctly expected.

Of course, as has been mentioned in comments, modelling the human body as linear resistor may not be that great a model. Also, physiological damage isn't strictly proportional to the energy delivered (it also depends on where in the body it is delivered).

Comment: P = voltage^2 / resistance and P = current^2 * resistance are equivalent formulations (since current = voltage/resistance by Ohm's law).
So of course, my problem remains, regardless of the formulation.
E.g., in your example with 1000 ohms, a one second exposure would give a 48.4 J energy, which is again ridiculously low and in contradiction with the fact that touching a 220V plug with a wet hand should be lethal.

Comment: @Antoine, the main point is that the (typical) source is constant voltage rather than constant current. And this leads to a different (and more realistic) conclusion than your calculations. 48 J is not much energy if you are thinking about electrical burn hazard. But if you are thinking about disruption of the nervous system (leading to ventricular fibrillation) it is quite a lot.

Comment: Where do you get your judgement about the energy required to meess up the function of the heart? What energy do you think is required? Howch energy is used by a pacemaker in one second?

Comment: @nasu, normally we talk about the current needed to disturb the heart, rather than the energy. About 30 mA AC is enough to cause fibrillation. You can calculate how much power would be absorbed (by the whole body) in delivering 30 mA through the chest (maybe 1 W with low contact resistance). And consider that much less than 1 s exposure is needed to dangerously shock someone, the energy required must not be very many joules. (Alternately you could work out the energy used in an individual nervous signal and compare with that, but I don't have useful numbers on hand to do that calculation)

Comment: @The photon Sorry, my question was for the OP.  It was supposed to be right after his comment but you were faster.